# Speed up App Script code for deleting rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with two columns. in the first one there is a date and in the second one there might be a text. I want to delete all rows where the date is in the past or the second column is empty.

```
for (var row = lastRow; row >= 1; row--) {
  if (sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue() < today || sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue() == "") {
     sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

This code is very slow because it has to access every cell. But I currently can't think of a better way... But there should be one.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Luisa

Comment: The easiest way is to read the data into an array, copy only the rows you want to keep into a new array, and then overwrite your sheet with the new information. Do you have formulas or just values?

Comment: Great idea! Worked perfectly fine!